# Issues with WindowBuilder in Eclipse (Kepler)

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I already have the partial answer to my question but I have a specific coding related question on how to circumnavigate an issue with the WindowBuilder GUI.

Basically, I am developing a login screen just to get used to Java's application development, getting used to JFrames and other such objects. I have used the WindowBuilder GUI to construct the Application Window and I have populated it with the necessary items. I coded in an action listener for one of the JButtons but when I go back to the Design tab (GUI) it gives me an error as follows: java.lang.error: new JTextField()

As far as I know the issue is that I haven't implemented action listeners and other such things to the rest of the objects in my code. My question is: if the object is a textfield why would it need an action listener? Is there some other object similar to an action listener I can implement and leave blank just so the WindowBuilderGUI doesn't crash?

Comment: Please provide the code where the error is listed.

Comment: Eclipse Kepler is *ancient*; why are you using a five year old version? As for circumnavigation, just keep sailing in one direction.

Comment: There is no error in the code as such, simply when I try to open the design tab it isn't able to open the Window Builder GUI. The error mentioned above only started occurring after I coded in an Action Listener for one of the JButtons, before that I could switch between the Source and Design tabs without problem. 

Elliot; which version is the most recent? I know Kepler is outdated but I didn't realize it was that archaic.